# SSIS: script task version 15.0 script that is not supported when deployed in active batch

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2017

Error:

> Description: There was an exception while loading Script Task from XML: System.Exception: The Script Task "ST_b7d198f240cd42ed864706faee2f4f58" uses version 15.0 script that is not supported in this release of Integration Services. To run the package, use the Script Task to create a new VSTA script. In most cases, scripts are converted automatically to use a supported version, when you open a SQL Server Integration Services package in %SQL_PRODUCT_SHORT_NAME% Integration Services.
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask.LoadFromXML(XmlElement elemProj, IDTSInfoEvents events)
> End Error

We upgraded SSIS packages from VS2013 to VS 2019 and tried running through active batch job and this is the error i got.
FYI- I changed deployed target version from "SQL Server 2014" to "SQL Server 2019"

When i change my target version to "sql Server 2014" it works fine.
Do i need to install any higher version for SSMS? If yes, can you please let me know what and where to download.

SSMS version 14.0
Visual studio 2019
Any solution?

Thanks
S

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? Sounds like you have SQL Server 2014, and thus target server 2014 fixes the problem, because that's the version you have.

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 14.0.17213.0

Comment: That's the version of SSMS you're using. I asked what version of SQL Server you're using.

Comment: Could you run `select @@VERSION` on your database and share the result here?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Jun 18 2020 16:54:11   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation

Comment: @Larnu can you please give some light on how to fix this issue.

Comment: @casenonsensitive can you please give some light on how to fix this issue.

Comment: @swathi it's possible that in your script task some DLLs are referenced from the old sql server version. One way of updating all of it is to update the target version of the solution, then recreate the script task with the sources from the old ones. Then the new DLLs get referenced and it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Run this query in SSMS to find out your SQL Server version.

```
select @@VERSION
```

Open your SSIS package in Visual Studio.

- Right click on your project in Visual Studio and select properties.
- Go to Configuration Properties > General > Deployment Target Version > TargetServerVersion.
- Select appropriate version of SQL Server here.
- Rebuild and re-deploy it.

[image]